# SQLite net Extension one to many relationship Windows Phone

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using sqlite net extension to create one to many relationship for 2 tables that am using there are tables in my C# code i follow tutorial in official site https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

```
[Table("Stock")]
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}
[Table("Valuation")]
public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code to create Stockobject and insert it to Db

```
var valuation = new List<Valuation>();
        valuation.Add(new Valuation { Price = 1 });

        var stock = new Stock();
        stock.Valuations = valuation;

        db.InsertWithChildren(stock);
```

but when i debug code and read stock data from db it shows me null for list of valuation what is problem here ?

That'is how it shows to me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `db.GetWithChildren<Stock>()` instead of `db.Table<Stock>()`.

Example from twincoders:

```
// Get the object and the relationships
var storedValuation = db.GetWithChildren<Valuation>(valuation.Id);
```